# Tinymce: How to trigger autocomplete when I do execCommand('mceInsertContent', '#')

Tags: tinymce-5

When I press the button do execCommand('mceInsertContent', '#') and insert # to the tinymce editor, but the autocompleter doesnt display.

The image: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Hey I managed to do it this way (tested with TinyMCE 6.7)

```js
editor.ui.registry.addButton("addMentionUser", {
  text: "User",
  onAction: () => {
    editor.insertContent("$");
    editor.fire("keypress");
  },
});
```